# Is Sencha Touch 2 supported by android OS?

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

Is Sencha Touch 2 supported by Android? Also, is senchatouch2 backward compatible with previous versions of android? If not then which all versions of android are supported by Sencha Touch 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Sencha Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?123118-Device-compatabilty-info):

> Currently, Sencha Touch supports Webkit browsers, more specifically,
>   iOS 3+ and Android 2.0+ (note that below Android 2.0 is not supported,
>   so Android 1.6 which is what older devices run is not supported).

Comment: i made an apk for android 2.1 and i tried to run it on android 4.0.3 but there was just a white screen.could there be a reason behind that??

Comment: Android 2.1 is not supported by Sencha Touch 2: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?188298-Sencha-Touch-2.x-application-is-not-working-on-Android-2.1-Emulator(API-Level-7)&p=757550&viewfull=1#post757550

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a official documentation of which Android versions are supported! In this blog posting, Sencha mentions that Android 3.x is not supported!

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?186178-Phonegap-1.5-Sencha-Touch-2-has-problems-on-android-3.0

So, it sounds like just 2.x and 4.x are supported (2.3 and 4.1 work for me, but I'm having some trouble with 4.0.4).